# Timed Color change HTML

Tags: javascript, html

i have table that needs to change color every 3 seconds. I have wrote a function that can change the color once but do not know how to do it in intervals.

HTML table code

```
<tr id="contacts_row<?php echo $i; ?>" class="row">
   <td><?php echo $row_color_test['fname'] . " " . $row_color_test['lname'] ; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row_color_test['phone']; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Function to change color once

```
function changeColor(color)
{
    var list = document.querySelectorAll(".row");
    var index;
    for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
        list[index].style.color = color;
    }
}
```

I tried the following which dint work

```
var array = new Array("violet","indigo","blue","green","yellow","orange","red");


function intervalChange()
{
   var counter=0;
   while(counter<7)
    {
       changeColor(array[counter]);
       counter++;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong or is there a better solution??

Comment: your `while` loop is missing a closing brace, also it is unlikely you want one at all. Use [`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Comment: @musefan its a typo here..had the closing brace in actual code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ignore the while loop and rather go for `setInterval`
Try This if it works

```
function intervalChange()
{
    var int=setInterval(function()
        {
            changeColor(array[counter]);
            counter++;
            if(counter==6){ counter=0; }
        },3000);
}
```

Use clearInterval to stop change

Comment: I imagine your days are 8 hours shorter than mine

Comment: @musefan I did not get you.

Comment: i somehow had it in mind that he wanted 3 secs interval..dunno how.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need the [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) method. This will allow a function to be called at a given interval until cancelled.

```
var myRecurringFunction = function(){ console.writeLine("Hello World"); }
var clearVariable = setInterval(myRecurringFunction, 2000); // 2000 miliseconds = 2 seconds
```

Every 2 seconds `myRecurringFunction` will be called.

If you need to stop the timer for some reason it is as simple as the [clearInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) method.

```
clearInterval(clearVariable);
```

Here's a JSFiddle with a bit of a rework on your code: http://jsfiddle.net/qzUCP/

```
function changeColor(color)
{
    var list = document.querySelectorAll(".row");
    var index;
    for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
        list[index].style.color = color;
    }
}

var array = new Array("violet","indigo","blue","green","yellow","orange","red");
var currentColorIndex = 0;

function intervalChange() {
    if(currentColorIndex >= array.length) currentColorIndex = 0;
    changeColor(array[currentColorIndex]);
    currentColorIndex++;
}

setInterval(intervalChange, 3000)
```

Comment: your first line of code is missing the closing brace... they're not getting much love on this question

Comment: Missing curly brace added. A fiddle and working cleanup of the asker's code has to be worth some love :D

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `setInterval()` function (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to set up a timer that will call the function to color.

Mayur's answer is perfect, except to get it to run every 3 seconds, change the 2000 to 3000. That's milliseconds, so you want 3000 there.

Comment: If you want to make comments on another person's answer then please do it by making a comment on the answer (when you have earned the rep to do so of course)

Comment: Thanks. I posted my answer, and then saw his after I posted mine, and since I couldn't comment/edit his, I figured the easiest place to do it was my answer. I'll keep that in mind for the future.